# Gradle script for xunit test does nothing or throws execCommand == null

Tags: .net, gradle, cmd, xunit

I'm trying to create a gradle script to run xunit test cases for my .net project. The script looks like:

```
task xunitTests {
   String contents = ""
   FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: 'Unit Test', 
   includes: ['**/bin/Debug/**/[Project]*UnitTest.dll'], exclude:['**/bin/Debug/**/*[Project].dll'])
   def reportDir = new File("${buildDir}",'report/xUnit')
   tree.each { path ->
      if (!executedDll.contains(path.name)) {
         def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
         exec {
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'packages\\xunit.runner.console.2.2.0\\tools\\xunit.console.exe \"$path\" -xml xunit.xml'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        executedDll.add(path.name)
        println "Output:\n$stdout"
    } else {
       println "Excluded already executed dll $path.name"
    }
  }
}
```

After I run the xunitTests task the output I get is the task is up-to-date and the build is successful but I don't see any execution on console. Now when I execute the following code:

```
task xunitTests (type:Exec) {
   String contents = ""
   FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: 'Unit Test', 
includes: ['**/bin/Debug/**/[Project]*UnitTest.dll'], exclude:['**/bin/Debug/**/*[Project].dll'])
   def reportDir = new File("${buildDir}",'report/xUnit')
   tree.each { path ->
      if (!executedDll.contains(path.name)) {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'D:\\LIS\\LIS.Encompass\\packages\\xunit.runner.console.2.2.0\\tools\\xunit.console.exe \"$path\" -xml xunit.xml'
        standardOutput = stdout
        executedDll.add(path.name)
        println "Output:\n$stdout"
    } else {
        println "Excluded already executed dll $path.name"
    }
}
```

I get error as "execCommand == null!". What am I missing here? I just need to execute the list of test dll's to get the output xml.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally not how it works unfortunately - [read](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) how task of type Exec works. `commandLine` can be configured once at *configuration* time, here's a little sample (I assume you can pass multiple paths to xunit):

```
task xunitTests (type:Exec) {
  def paths = []
  def tree = fileTree(dir: 'Unit Test', includes: ['**/bin/Debug/**/[Project]*UnitTest.dll'], exclude:['**/bin/Debug/**/*[Project].dll'])
  def paths = tree.files*.absolutePath
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "D:\\LIS\\LIS.Encompass\\packages\\xunit.runner.console.2.2.0\\tools\\xunit.console.exe ${paths.join(' ')} -xml xunit.xml"
}
```

You can try it out, unfortunately I can't test it.

If multiple paths can be passed as an argument to xunit you need to create multiple tasks and a root task (that will depend on all subtasks):

```
task testAll
def tree = fileTree(dir: 'Unit Test', includes: ['**/bin/Debug/**/[Project]*UnitTest.dll'], exclude:['**/bin/Debug/**/*[Project].dll'])
tree.eachWithIndex { f, idx ->
  task "test$idx"(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "packages\\xunit.runner.console.2.2.0\\tools\\xunit.console.exe ${f.absolutePath} -xml xunit.xml"
  } 
  testAll.dependsOn "test$idx"
}
```

No output redirection for now, first things first.

Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: I tried the first solution that you suggested and it did not work. The error I received was "must specify at least one assembly" and the exception was command cmd finished with non-zero exit value 3. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Where that message: _must specify at least one assembly_ comes from exactly? I suppose that not from `Exec` task. I may try to help you, however can't test my suggestions.

Comment: @jugal this message comes from here: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.console/CommandLine.cs#L134, there's something a piece of configuration missing..